# What does Windows use to determine how old a profile is when implementing the CleanupProfiles registry setting?

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-registry, xml, microsoft-intune

How does the Windows registry setting `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System!CleanupProfiles` determine the age of a profile on Windows 10?

I have tried to understand the setting, which is referenced in the
following web site and in the XML file:

https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.UserProfiles::CleanupProfiles

```
<Computer>
    <VersionDirectory>1</VersionDirectory>
    <VersionSysvol>1</VersionSysvol>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <ExtensionData>
        <Extension xmlns:q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Registry" xsi:type="q1:RegistrySettings">
          <q1:Policy>
            <q1:Name>Delete user profiles older than a specified number of days on system restart</q1:Name>
            <q1:State>Enabled</q1:State>
            <q1:Explain>This policy setting allows an administrator to automatically delete user profiles on system 
            restart that have not been used within a specified number of days. Note: One day is interpreted as 24
            hours after a specific user profile was accessed. If you enable this policy setting, the User Profile
            Service will automatically delete on the next system restart all user profiles on the computer that have 
            not been used within the specified number of days. If you disable or do not configure this policy
            setting, User Profile Service will not automatically delete any profiles on the next system restart.
            </q1:Explain>
            <q1:Supported>At least Windows Vista</q1:Supported>
            <q1:Category>System/User Profiles</q1:Category>
            <q1:Numeric>
                <q1:Name>Delete user profiles older than (days)</q1:Name>
                <q1:State>Enabled</q1:State>
                <q1:Value>45</q1:Value>
            </q1:Numeric>
          </q1:Policy>
        </Extension>
        <Name>Registry</Name>
     </ExtensionData>
</Computer>
```

I examined this and the rest of the file myself. I also inputted the the code into ChatGPT, asking what eventually happens with the "q1: Value". But I could not find out what happens with the value.

I saw on this user guide https://woshub.com/delete-old-user-profiles-gpo-powershell/ the author says the policy determines the age of the user profile by checking two entries in the RegistryEditor. These being "LocalProfileLoadTimeHigh" and "LocalProfileLoadTimeLow". But at no point in the guide did the author say how they knew this, so I could not confirm whether it was true.

However, when I was Google searching about how to apply the policy to Intune, before I got to the point of examining how it works, many users on this Reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/xqi6n6/does_the_gpo_delete_user_profiles_older_than_a/ claim that the policy no longer works in Windows 8 and later. This is because it checks for a file which is updated by Windows no matter if the user logs into their account on the machine, according to the redditors.

After reading these two pages in particular, I am now conflicted whether the policy can or can't work properly on Windows 10 or 11.

I have Google searched how GPO's interact with the RegistryEditor, to find out what the policy checks for myself, and this link: https://theitbros.com/add-modify-and-delete-registry-keys-using-group-policy/ does describe it in a helpful way. I gather the policy can be given an "action" on the Registry, so CleanupProfiles probably "Updates" or "Replaces" somewhere in the Registry, using the value 45 in my case. Does the RegistryEditor do something in the background when the threshold of 45 has been reached? I would try and use Process Monitor to see this but I'm not too sure how to test it as the machine I use doesn't have any valid, old profiles on it.

Please could you point me in the right direction to finding out what CleanupProfiles checks?

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: This is a registry setting that has nothing to do with Group Policy, except as a deployment mechanism to toggle the setting.

Comment: To expand on what @GregAskew is saying: GPO is usually only setting "switches" in the registry, and then local processes check those switches and actually take action based on their setting. So any registry key this GPO may be setting is not the ACTUAL value the system checks to determine how old a profile is. Further, the Reddit thread you linked contains an extensive discussion of what that policy might actually be polling as well as alternate ways to accomplish that. I agree with them that a PS script is likely the best way to implement what you want. Have you tried using their solutions?

Comment: Thank you both for your helpful comments and for the edit of my question Greg. @music2myear thank you for the explanation, that is very helpful. I wanted to avoid using a PS Script because I was under the impression this ADMX was fully functional and designed by Microsoft. I wouldn't have to hope for the best by creating my own PS script. Also, I have been warned that some PS scripts, if not written properly can remove profiles and risk deleting their entire Sharepoint directories their account is linked to.

Comment: You do things carefully and you test thoroughly. PS only does what you tell it to, so tell it carefully to do only what you want it to do. Don't just find a rando PS script somewhere and run it without reading and understanding it fully yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The User Profile Service keeps track when a profile is being created. The Windows user profile service keeps track of when a user profile was created through the use of the registry. Each user profile has an associated registry key, typically located in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList registry hive. Within this key, there is a subkey for each user profile, identified by a unique Security Identifier (SID).

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am looking into some things about the ProfileList with my MSP. I have a feeling the policy I'm using is working fine, it is just ignoring some profiles which are on the list because they are missing the two subkeys mentioned in the first article I linked.

Comment: Then you need to enable "User Environment Debug Logging"  to pinpoint that. https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c01682616&docLocale=en_US